# Assigning a user label (string) to a pid?

Tags: linux, pid

In my use case, I have to launch many processes with the same name. This confuses me a lot because I can distinguish them only by checking the PID.
I was wondering if there exists some kind of additional field/info/label that the user can set/retrieve for this purpose.

I already know that I can rename a process using for example:

```
 #include <sys/prctl.h>
 prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "Test");
```

but I was looking for alternate,less-invasive solutions which do not change the process name..

Comment: When one process spawns more i use for example: ```printf "%s\n" $(pidof apache2) | sort``` and the first one is the main process. Is that usefull for you?

Comment: You could use an environment variable, with a different value or name per process.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even want this?
Every process knows who has started it, as you can see in this excerpt of `ps -ef`:

```
Linux Prompt>ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /init
root         7     1  0 15:05 tty1     00:00:00 /init
scampsd      8     7  0 15:05 tty1     00:00:00 -bash
scampsd     80     8  0 15:08 tty1     00:00:00 ps -ef
```

The information you want is in the `UID` column.

Same with the well-known `top` command (just an excerpt):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0    8940    316    272 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.10 init
    7 root      20   0    8940    224    180 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 init
    8 scampsd   20   0   18212   3836   3732 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.16 bash
   81 scampsd   20   0   18920   2144   1528 R   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 top
```

The information you want is in the `USER` column.

So I don't see any reason to add information, which is already available.